# Edit android:onClick value

Tags: java, android

```
TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(text_value);
```

This string edits the `android:text` value.
But if I want to edit the `andoid:onClick` value, what should I do?
For example:

```
// from:
android:onClick("action(1)");
// to:
android:onClick("action(2)");
```

Thanks a lot `:)`

*PS: sorry for any error, I'm Italian :(*

Comment: You can't do that. Add a listener.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot edit the android:onClick programmatically in android try [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)

```
text.setOnClickListener(this);    
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

Comment: I tried this: `share_btn.setOnClickListener( (Condividi(data[position])) );` but nothing. The function's name is `Condividi()` and if I create a button with the `onClick` attribute `Condividi("text")` it works, so the problem isn't the function. What's the error? Thanks a lor :)

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29), providing an implementation of `View.OnClickListener` as argument.

Nitpick: Calling `setText()` doesn't "edit" the XML attribute value. It just changes the same `TextView` internal value that is influenced by the attribute at construction time. The same goes for `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the method in the activity class.

res/layout/main.xml

```
  <FrameLayout
      ....>
         <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
                ..../>

         <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:onClick="actionTwo"
                .../>
  </FrameLayout>


  class MyActivity extends Activity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }


        public void actionOne(View view) {
               // the action here
        }

        public void actionTwo(View view) {
               // the action here
               TextView textView = (TextView) findById(R.id.text1);
               textView.setText("Uhuuu funcionou!!!");
        }
  }
```